# Trigger opportunity Product Lost

Tags: apex, trigger, opportunity-lineitem

I have a custom checkbox Lost__c on opportunity product so when you edit the product added on the opportunity, you can set that the product isn’t sold.

I want that if the checkbox is true:

1. Copy Unit Price in a custom field named OfferedPrice__c
2. Set  UnitPrice to zero

I have written the following code:

```
trigger LostProduct on OpportunityLineItem (before update)
{
  Set<Id> Ids = new Set<Id>();
  \\ GET THE NEW OPPORTUNITY lINE ITEM ID  

  for (OpportunityLineItem oppli: Trigger.new){
        Ids.add(oppli.id);
  }     

  \\ GET THE OLD OPPORTUNITY lINE ITEM                 
  List <OpportunityLineItem> oppsec=[Select Id,OfferedPrice__c,UnitPrice From  OpportunityLineItem  Where id in: Ids];    
  List<OpportunityLineItem> ListOpp = new List<OpportunityLineItem>();           

  for (OpportunityLineItem opproduct: Trigger.new){  
         if (opproduct.Lost__c==True){
           opproduct.OfferedPrice__c= opproduct.UnitPrice;
           Listopp.add(opproduct);        
         }  
  }  

  \\ SET FIELDS OF THE OLD RECORD          
  oppsec[0].OfferedPrice__c=Listopp[0].OfferedPrice__c;
  oppsec[0].UnitPrice=0;                 

  update(Oppsec);
}
```

but i get this error message:

> Apex trigger LostProduct caused an unexpected exception, contact your
>   administrator: LostProduct: execution of BeforeUpdate caused by:
>   System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id
>   00kJ0000006in6cIAA; first error: SELF_REFERENCE_FROM_TRIGGER, Object
>   (id = 00kJ0000006in6c) is currently in trigger LostProduct, therefore
>   it cannot recursively update itself: []: Trigger.LostProduct: line 23,
>   column 1

Where i am wrong? Do is necessary get the old record?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have a `before update` trigger on OpportunityLineItem, you don't need to use the update statement. You only need to set the values which you want to set.

Comment: Thank you very much!! :) All works now!I'am going to update the post with the solution!

Comment: @Enry: You shouldn't update your question with the solution since that will just confuse the posting. Instead, you should mark this answer as the solution and vote it up.